# Can I open exact place on google map?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps

I am developing custom map, and this how I put places:

```
        markers.add(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(49.788238, 73.1359273)).title("KFC"));
```

I show only marker and name. If user want to get more information he should open it on google map using this button
[image: how to open google map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZhuP.jpg)

I expect that user sees whole info [image: what i expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iArft.jpg)

But users see this [image: actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lugie.jpg)

Can I somehow set full link to marker. Or can I handle clicking this button on first image.

**UPDATE**
I did not do anything, just added marker and when I click to this marker i see two buttons which is added not by me.
[my class](https://github.com/turlygazhy/MapWithMarkerExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapwithmarker/MapsMarkerActivity.java)

My goal is see exact place on google maps when I click to button from 1st image

**UPDATE 2** I found where this buttons can be switched on/off

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled
```

I actually need this buttons, can I handle of clicking this buttons, or can I put full URL to exact place to marker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here we set listener for doing what we want

```
this.map.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> {
        String uri = linkMap.get(marker);//get your link
        View openInGoogleButton = findOpenInGoogleButton(root);

        if (uri == null || openInGoogleButton == null) return false;

        openInGoogleButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            fragmentActivity.startActivity(intent);
        });

        return false;
    });
```

method for finding open in google toolbar button

```
private View findOpenInGoogleButton(View v) {
    View openInGoogleButton = null;

    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
        for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
            openInGoogleButton = findOpenInGoogleButton(vg.getChildAt(i));
            if (openInGoogleButton != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } else if (v.getTag() != null
            && "GoogleMapOpenGmmButton".equalsIgnoreCase(v.getTag().toString())) {
        openInGoogleButton = v;
    }

    return openInGoogleButton;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass coordinates in your intent to open Google maps, you do not get the place details. If you want to have the place details too (*as in your case*), you need to pass the name or place_id of the place.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=centurylink+field.
```

Source: [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started)

Putting this above query in your intent Uri , results in the marker location along with the place details in Google maps of *century link field*. You can put your desired place name in the query and get the results.

For more info [Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started).

Happy coding!

Comment: can i put Uri in MarkerOptions? Google maps is opened by default button (see 1st image) and I dont know where i can handle of clicking to this button, do you?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about what you want to achieve. But if you just want to open Google maps on button click then you can make a button and handle it's click in `onClickListener` where you can start the intent of the opening google maps.